# Ignite Web Session Clustering with standalone nodes

Tags: session, ignite

I'd like use web session clustering in my application.

I checked a page https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/web-session-clustering
and There is no way to set standalone ignite nodes..
only like this 
...

```
<!-- Specify Ignite configuration (relative to META-INF folder or Ignite_HOME). -->
<context-param>
   <param-name>IgniteConfigurationFilePath</param-name>
   <param-value>config/default-config.xml </param-value>
</context-param>
```

how to set server ip:port at web.xml file??  or is there other way to set??

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`config/default-config.xml` is a path to a full [Ignite XML configuration file](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/understanding-configuration#spring-xml-configuration), which will allow you to specify node addresses and anything else that you like.

You can configure it as client mode and make it join cluster of stand-alone server nodes.